# Disable Microsoft ehome IR Transceiver in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, device-manager

I need to disable the IR receiver device on my Fujitsu Amilo xi3650 laptop. Its running Windows 7 Pro. Its picking up IR signals intended for a separate HTPC running Windows 7 HP.

In device manager I've tried to disable the Microsoft eHome IR Transceiver device, however I guess its been marked as essential hardware as the Disable button is greyed out and unavailable.

Uninstalling the IR transceiver device driver only works till I reboot then it automatically re-installs.

I had a look in the bios but didn't see an obvious way to disable the hardware from there.

Is there a way (short of sticking some tape over the sensor) of turning the receiver off permanently?

I don't want to stop all hardware automatically installing on my machine just to get round this (I've seen this as an option when googling).

Comment: why not unplug the IR, or is it permanently attached?

Comment: Its in a laptop, I think its soldered on one of the PCBs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the subtle step of simply covering the IR receiver with a (neatly trimmed) piece of electric tape.

There really ought to be a better way of going about it than this!

Answer (score 2):

1. Click **Start**, right-click **My Computer**, and then click **Properties**.
2. On the **Hardware** tab, click **Device Manager**.
3. Expand **Human Interface Devices**.
4. Double-click **Microsoft eHome Infrared Transceiver**.
5. On the **Driver** tab, click **Uninstall**, and then click **OK**.

Comment: Already done that - just reinstalls on reboot.

Comment: BIOS. Advanced tab - look for infa red, or Bluetooth...

Comment: As stated, I had checked that already, but I rechecked anyway and there are no options. (Its actually the most simplistic BIOS I've seen)

Comment: Is there something in the control panel settings under Turn Windows Features On or Off?