# *Permanently* disable/uninstall eHome infrared transceiver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, infrared

I don't even *have* an infrared receiver on my desktop, the driver is probably for the circuitry on the motherboard. I want to disable and get rid of the damn thing as it interferes with the tilde key used as a console shortcut when playing Fallout 3, **so that it doesn't show up again after the next reboot**. Already seen [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/323979/disable-microsoft-ehome-ir-transceiver-in-windows-7), which concerns an actual hardware transceiver.
I'm running Windows 10, if that makes any difference.

Comment: You would still have to disable it in the BIOS or Device Manager for it to not show up again (whether the physical external antenna exists or not).  A work around would be to go into the IR device/program settings and switch it from the ~ key to another key that wouldn't interfere with Fallout.

Comment: But there's no separate software for this, all I have is the device manager entry. I didn't even know it was there till I went looking for it.

Comment: the ~ key is being assigned to it somehow.  Have you looked at the device before uninstalling it?  You can actually modify some settings at the driver level.